# Loop through 2 arrays and find differences with a twist

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Ok so this is kind of a hard one for me to wrap my head around so im hoping that one of you guys might be able to help. A little context, this is for an updater im writing that grabs an xml list of files from a cdn, then compares that vs an older list to look for file differences so i know which files are out of date and need to be redownloaded. Right now i am unable to find a proper solution for this.

Currently i have 3 arrays. Array1, Array2, and DiffArray. 
Array1 stores the xml entries from the CDN..ie the master
Array2 stores the old entries of what we currently have..ie the slave
Array3 stores the differences of what has changed between the 2.

Heres a sample bit of info thats in each array. Note that each new line is parsed into a separate index of their corresponding array

Array1:

```
cbt/ar/816.mp3
2019-06-05T16:40:33.212Z
cbt/ar/817.mp3
2019-06-05T16:40:31.509Z
cbt/ar/818.mp3
2019-04-05T16:40:30.978Z
cbt/ar/819.mp3
2019-04-05T16:40:29.807Z
```

Array2:

```
cbt/ar/816.mp3
2019-04-05T16:40:33.212Z
cbt/ar/817.mp3
2019-04-05T16:40:31.509Z
cbt/ar/818.mp3
2019-04-05T16:40:30.978Z
cbt/ar/819.mp3
2019-04-05T16:40:29.807Z
```

a couple things to note:
1.) this is a list of a file name, and its last modified date
2.) As you can see, array1 has a new file for both 816.mp3 and 817.mp3

The idea is to see that, note which files are different, then redownload those files with the more current version.

This is what i currently have, but as you can see its not the right solution for the job:

```
var a = [];
      for (var x = 0; x < remoteArray.length; x++) {
        a[remoteArray[x]] = true;

      }

      for (var y = 0; y < localArray.length; y++) {
        if (a[localArray[y]]) {
          delete a[localArray[y]];
        } else {
          a[localArray[y]] = true;
        }
      }

      for (var z in a) {
        diffArray.push(z);
        log.info("::DIFFERENCES::" + z);
      }
    }
```

This current code only outputs the actual literal differences and doesn't really help me know which file is different so that i can update it

Comment: please add the array in literal notation - and the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to first transform your data into a list of objects representing each file. It is not the most performant approach but will make things clearer and easier to maintain.

```
function transformFilesList(array) {
    var files = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
        files.push({
            name: array[i],
            modified: array[i + 1]
        });
    }
    return files;
}

var remote = transformFilesList(remoteArray);
var local = transformFilesList(localArray);
var needsDownload = remote.filter(file => {
    let match = local.find(localFile => localFile.name === file.name);
    // We need to download if there is no local file with this name or its modification date is older than the remote one
    return !match || match.modified < file.modified;
});

console.log('List of files to (re)download', needsDownload);
// Each file in this list will be an object { name, modified }
```

If you cannot use features like `Array.prototype.filter` or arrow functions (old browsers or Node versions), an old alternative to get needsDownload would be:

```
var needsDownload = [];
for (var i = 0; i < remote.length; i++) {
    var found;
    for (var j = 0; j < local.length; j++) {
        if (remote[i].name === local[j].length) {
            found = local[j];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found || found.modified < remote[i].modified) {
        needsDownload.push(found);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much. One question though. How can i access the needsDownloaded var outside of the functions scope to use it in other places, say in a "download" class or something? This way i can actually download it lol.

Comment: @IgnitionK6 you could return it from the function (`return needsDownload;`). Then you can get your list with `var list = download.getList();` or whatever your function is called.

Comment: ive tried that. It seems when i call with var list = test2(remoteArray, localArray); i get [object Object], [object Object]

Comment: @IgnitionK6 it returns an array of objects, each containing a name and modified time. If you try to display it as part of a string it will call `.toString()` on it, which is the equivalent of `.join(',')`, which in turn calls `.toString()` on all its elements. On an object, this just returns the string `[object Object]`. If you want a string with the list of names you could do `list.map(file => file.name)` or to debug the full thing you could use `JSON.stringify(list)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the format you want the result in, but it identifies which files need to be updated:

```
# Make a dictionary matching each cdn file to its timestamp
cdn = {}
for i in range(0,len(Array1),2):
    cdn[Array1[i]] = Array1[i+1]

# Make an array of files needing to be updated
update = []
for i in range(0,len(Array2),2):
    path = Array2[i]
    # If file is in CDN and the one there is newer, add it to update
    if path in cdn and cdn[path] > Array2[i+1]:
        update.append( path )
```